# Reduce or remove Shared Memory

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card, bios, gpu

I'm experiencing low memory issues as you can see: [Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZROA.png).

I have a X550JX Asus laptop. It has 4GB of ram and 4GB of GPU memory (GeForce GTX 950m). I have windows 10 64bit recently updated running. I think the reason is that 1992 MB of my memory is shared with my GPU and Intel HD Graphics. Only chrome is opened and my windows is fresh so there are no startup apps.

Both My GPU and my Intel HD Graphics are using 1992 MB of my Memory as Shared Memory:

[Intel HD Graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hEKt.png), [GeForce GTX 950m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGuKS.png) (I used dxdiag command to get these information.)

Is there any way to remove or reduce the shared memory? I've already scanned through my BIOS settings and found nothing related. Any answers will be appreciated.

P.s: Sorry for bad English

Comment: "Shared" memory is not necessarily *used* memory, Unless you are using a significant amount more than the 4GB on your graphics card, which is unlikely.

Comment: But there is no other reason that my memory is low like that.

Comment: 2.3GB of 4GB used is normal. It is close to what I see on my laptop.